# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

A simple email validation script keeps failing on me.

```
if(!preg_match('^[^@]{1,63} @ [^@]{1,255}$', $input)) {
    return false;
}
```

It should be simple, ensure just one '@' symbol, correct lengths for local and domain address. But valid emails keep failing to pass this test. In the error_log I also keep getting a message that '@' is an undefined variable. Am I suppose to escape it? Putting backslashes in front of them didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

*edit: I guess I should specify, there is a whole lot more to the email validation script, I just didn't post because those parts are working fine. This is clearly not the only validation but it is the only one that keeps error-ing on me.

Comment: Why are there spaces around the `@`?

Comment: This would also return true for `!"£$%^&*() @ !"£$%^&*()`. Bad times.

Comment: Spaces are just to make it easy on the eyes. Real version is without. Probably shouldn't have added that though.

Comment: @Renzo:  You do need to remove the spaces because those are characters that would need to match the input.  So it would match "a @ b.c" but not "a@b.c".

Answer (score 4):

Validating an email with just a simple regex is bound to fail. Check this article, which goes through the lengths of properly validating an e-mail address with PHP:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,0

From the comments there, you might also check the filter_var function of PHP, which seems simple & effective (it's almost always better not to reinvent the wheel):

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
exit("E-mail is not valid");
}
```

Comment: Oh I realize. That is just one part of the validation, I do go through a lot of other steps, it's just that this is the one part in question that keeps erroring and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I see, nevertheless check if filter_var does the trick for you, after all it's built into PHP and why rebuild something that is already there and works? You could spend that time on other parts of your project :)

Comment: You realize that PHP-internally FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is in fact just a regex? (not the best one btw)

Comment: It probably is, but unless you have very specific requirements which require you to reinvent the wheel I still prefer using readymade solutions before baking something myself. That of course is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use that regex to validate an email address. Really.

Anyway, your problem is with `preg_match` syntax, which as first parameter accepts a pattern in the format `/ [...] /`, where / are PCRE [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

So your call would be:

```
 if(!preg_match('/^[^@]{1,63}@[^@]{1,255}$/', $input)) {
```

But please, don't use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mid that `preg_match()` and other `preg_*()` functions aren't reliable because they return either `0` or `false` on fail, so a simple if won't throw on error.

Consider using [CleanRegex](https://github.com/Danon/pattern):

```
if (pattern(('^[^@]{1,63}@[^@]{1,255}$')->matches($input)) 
{
    // Matches! :)
}
```